# Spec(A((t))) is connected if and only if Spec(A) is connected

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Please, check my proof. I need this to be sure that I haven't lost sight of something. I prove the following statement:

$$
\text{Spec }A((t)) \text{ is connected if and only if Spec }A \text{ is connected} 
$$
I know that condition for the ring $R$ $\text{Spec }R$ is not connected is equivalent to $R = R_1 \times R_2$. So I try to prove my statement by direct products.

In one direction, let $A = B \times C$. Then $A((t)) \cong (B\times C)((t))\cong B((t))\times C((t))$. So this part is trivial.

Other direction: let $A((t)) \cong B \times C$. Consider trivial case: let $t \in B$, $ t^{-1} \in B$, then $B = B'((t))$ and we have $A((t)) \cong B'((t))\times C \cong (B'\times C)((t))$. Then we have $A \cong B'\times C$. Another case is $t \in B$, $t^{-1} \in C$, thus we have $1 = 1*1=t*t^{-1}$. Contradiciton with $A((t)) \cong B \times C$.

If my proof has mistakes, please, tell me about them.

Comment: Maybe I'm being silly but $(B\times C)((t))\cong B((t))\times C((t))$ looks off. It might help to use the characterisation $R$ is connected iff. it has no nontrivial idempotents